# How to get the data type in a vector using template?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm writing a function template like this:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass() {}

template <typename A, typename B>
auto func(A<B>& data) {
    return MyClass<B>();
}
```

So I can using the function like this:

```
vector<int> vi;    auto a = func(vi);
vector<string> vs;    auto b = func(vs);
list<int> li;    auto c = func(li);
list<string> ls;    auto d = func(ls);
```

But obviously it's not allowed. How should I write a template to reach my goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare `A` as [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter), otherwise you can't use it as `A<B>` in the function parameter declaration since it's not considered as template.

```
template <template <typename...> class A, typename B>
auto func(A<B>& data) {
    // ... use B as the data type ...
}
```

Another way is STL containers (including [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)) have a member type as `value_type`, you can use it as

```
template <typename A>
auto func(A& data) {
    using B = typename A::value_type;
    // ... use B as the data type ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {};

template <template <typename, typename...> typename A, typename B, typename ... REST>
auto func(A<B,REST...>& data) {
    return MyClass<B>();
}
```